# How to update database table automatically?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table, which contains data from 3 another tables. This table I got with this code:

```
SELECT u.UserName, s.SysName, a.Version, a.Date, a.Activities, a.Changes

INTO dbo.Information

FROM dbo.Users as u, dbo.Systems as s, dbo.Activities as a

WHERE a.UserID = u.UserID
AND a.SysID = s.SysID;
```

After that I got a table, that shows me content of 3 tables (Users, Systems, Activities)

The problem is - i've created a table that shows me result for one single timestamp and i would like to have a table, that will store the informations from 3 tables each time automatically, so I could get updated table in DataGridVeiw-field in my WinForm each time i start my application.

Comment: **[`Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOIN`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)**

Comment: Can you clarify more on what you want to do

Comment: I don't understand you fully, but maybe you need `TRIGGER` that can make updates after some `INSERT` into table

Comment: Hello @Learning, I would like to create table "Information", which will combine data from 3 tables (Users, Systems and Activities). This tables must deliver data in some dataGridView in WindowsForm application, thats why i have decided to consolidate all of them in one table (Information) at first and then connect that table with dataGridView.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to create a table from those 3 tables for all users and sysIds? If so you probably want to look at creating a view.

Comment: what you need is call `VIEW`. Please take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Plz share more details as requested by, Solution could be in Trigger, View or even Temp Table. since we are not able to understand your objective its hard to say.. Do you want to move information in NEW table of you just want to show it for viewing or reporting?

Comment: The challenge here is that nobody understands what you want to do. I am certain the solution is pretty straight forward. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to ask a question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for information about Views. That is exactly what i looked for!

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about your Information table's data becoming stale then create a view and select from it or use a stored procedure to populate your dataGridView.

If you are talking about keeping historical information from the other tables in the Information table, you'll need to use triggers on the other tables.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.INFORMATION
AS
SELECT
  u.UserName
 ,s.[SysName]
 ,a.[Version]
 ,a.[Date]
 ,a.Activities
 ,a.[Changes]
FROM
  dbo.users u
  join dbo.Activities a on a.userid = u.userId
  join dbo.Systems s on s.sysid = a.sysid
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.INFORMATION
```